# Implement block one method until another method is invoked mechanism

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

So we have a class as below:

```
public static class BlockMethodtillAnotherCalled {
    
    public void doOnce() {
        
    }
    
    public void blockUntilCall() {

    }
}
```

And we want to achieve that all thread calling blockUntilCall() would be blocked till doOnce() is invoked.

A example as below:

T1.blockUntilCall -> print out "...is now block"

T2.blockUntilCall -> print out "...is now block"

T3.doOnce

T1.blockUntilCall -> print out "...is now released"

T2.blockUntilCall -> print out "...is now released"

Comment: What have you tried so far?  What ideas do you have?  What research have you done?

Answer (score 1):

You should check the description of package [`java.util.concurrent`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/package-summary.html#package.description), specifically the section named "**Synchronizers**".

> **Synchronizers**
>
> Five classes aid common special-purpose synchronization idioms.
>
> - [`Semaphore`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html) is a classic concurrency tool.
> - [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is a very simple yet very common utility for blocking until a given number of signals, events, or conditions hold.
> - A [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html) is a resettable multiway synchronization point useful in some styles of parallel programming.
> - A [`Phaser`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Phaser.html) provides a more flexible form of barrier that may be used to control phased computation among multiple threads.
> - An [`Exchanger`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Exchanger.html) allows two threads to exchange objects at a rendezvous point, and is useful in several pipeline designs.

In this case, a [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html) is a perfect match, using a countdown from 1.

> A `CountDownLatch` is initialized with a given *count*. The [`await`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await--) methods block until the current count reaches zero due to invocations of the [`countDown()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#countDown--) method, after which all waiting threads are released and any subsequent invocations of [`await`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html#await--) return immediately. This is a one-shot phenomenon -- the count cannot be reset. If you need a version that resets the count, consider using a [`CyclicBarrier`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CyclicBarrier.html).

Here is a scaled-down version of the example code from the javadoc of [`CountDownLatch`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CountDownLatch.html), fitted to the code in the question:

```java
public static class BlockMethodtillAnotherCalled {

    private CountDownLatch startSignal = new CountDownLatch(1);

    public void doOnce() {
        this.startSignal.countDown(); // let all threads proceed
    }

    public void blockUntilCall() {
        try {
            this.startSignal.await();
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            // proceed without the start signal
        }
    }
}
```